# Caused by: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.MalformedByteSequenceException: Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence

Tags: grails, invocationtargetexception

In windows 7 64bits, with JDK 1.7 update 17, Grails 2.2.1 in the console:

1 - when type "grails create-app helloworld" work fine. 
2-  cd "helloworld" work fine
3-  grails
| Loading Grails 2.2.1
| Error java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Caused by: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.MalformedByteSequenceException: Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence.

Now with this same software but in machine with windows 8, 64bits, with JDK 1.7 update 17, Grails 2.2.1, working fine.

Some software in the machine with windows 7 is causing the problem. I don´t have ANT environment set in windows 8, and windows 7, then this no is the problem.

anyone can help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have a library conflict somewhere. I would start with checking if  You have any other versions of xerces in your classpath. It may not be directly xerces, but some common library it uses.

Comment: Ok, Currently I remove the classpath, I have JAVA_HOME, M2_HOME, MW_HOME(Weblogic), ROO_HOME(Spring Roo), JAVA_DEV.   A few minutes remove all variables: M2_HOME, MW_HOME(Weblogic), ROO_HOME(Spring Roo), JAVA_DEV. Also I remove JRE for complete, close MS-DOS, and not is working, in PATH I remove bin folder from ROO, MW_HOME

Comment: Other Date:

Caused by: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.MalformedByteSequenceException: Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence.

I remove all configuration in project Grails encoding UTF-8 and I change for ISO-8859-1, only for test but the same problem was encountered, without UTF-8 in project the problem is present, this problem is in windows 7 64 bits, but in my windows8 64 bits if is working, I'm confused never happened something similar

Comment: try to run create app with -verbose and -stacktrace flags. This might help

Comment: More Info is the directory where type "grails" not have a project, grails loading work fine, but when type "grails" after grails create-app my-project in directory my-project(cd my-project), is where | Error java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
| Error Caused by: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.MalformedByteSequenceException: Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence.    

All error is:

Comment: | Loading Grails 2.2.1
| Error java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
| Error         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
| Error         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
| Error         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
| Error         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
.................. Error is more large

Comment: What're you trying to achieve by launching create-app script inside existing project?

Comment: ok maybe not write well, inside an empty folder, http://grails.org/Quick+Start, I type:"grails create-app my-project", after "cd my-project", and then "grails" thrown the error, not work with any command for example "grails create-controller ...." or some other, in My last test(20 minutes), download version Grails 2.1.0, minor version but the same error is thrown

Comment: I try with you recommendation "try to run create app with -verbose and -stacktrace flags. This might help", but the same problem with Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence. If not have ANT, MAVEN, WEBLOGIC, in environment variables, Which xerces which is causing the problem, because not have classpath(I remove for test)

Comment: I can't create project Grails with Ant or Maven because problem is present: | Error There was an error loading the BuildConfig: Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence. (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
C:\Grails\Grails Projects\ProyectoHello\my-project3>grails integrate-with --ant --stacktrace --verbose

Base Directory: C:\Grails\Grails Projects\ProyectoHello\my-project3
|Loading Grails 2.1.0
Error There was an error loading the BuildConfig: Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence.
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.MalformedByteSequenceException: Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8